# Rails - How to obfuscate js file on the fly with sprocket

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, obfuscation, sprockets

I recently had to obfuscate js assets in my rails app. Instead of doing it by hand for each file, I wanted to do it on the fly. Problem: there is no much js obfuscator running with rails and customizable.

Finally I decided to use https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator

I underline that in no case I intend to use this in production. It strictly limited for development and I'll "rake assets:precompile" when I push to prod.

First I installed node + javascript-obfuscator in Rails.root

```
npm install --save-dev javascript-obfuscator
```

in application.rb I added:

```
Sprockets.register_postprocessor('application/javascript', Transformer.new)
```

also in application.rb I added:

```
class Transformer
  def call(input)
    return {data: input[:data]} unless input[:data].to_s.include?("to_be_compiled")
    stamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
    File.open("tmp/obfuscate/tmp#{stamp}.js", "w+") do |f|
        f.write(input[:data])
    end

    parameters = " --compact true"
    parameters += " --controlFlowFlattening true"
    parameters += " --controlFlowFlatteningThreshold 1"
    parameters += " --debugProtection true"
    parameters += " --debugProtectionInterval true" 
    parameters += " --disableConsoleOutput true" 
    parameters += " --domainLock 'localhost'" 
    parameters += " --rotateStringArray true" 
    parameters += " --seed #{stamp}"
    parameters += " --selfDefending true" 
    parameters += " --stringArray true" 
    parameters += " --stringArrayEncoding true" 
    parameters += " --stringArrayThreshold 0.8" 
    parameters += " --unicodeEscapeSequence true"

    order = 'node node_modules/javascript-obfuscator/bin/javascript-obfuscator.js tmp/obfuscate/tmp'+stamp+'.js --output tmp/obfuscate/tmp_out'+stamp+'.js'+parameters 
    system(order)
    data = File.read("tmp/obfuscate/tmp_out"+stamp+".js") 
    system("rm -rf tmp/obfuscate/*")
    return { data: data }
  end
end
```

This will catch the js code after (post_processor) it is processed by Sprockets, write it in a tmp file, obfuscate this in tmp_out js file and return its content to the pipeline.

I just had to limit this to a few files of mine. So as you can read, the process will only be executed if the javascript which is being processed contain the string "to_be_compiled".

Note still that my files are js.jsx pre processed by Babel before Sprockets. So Babel enables me to add options: {comments: false, compact: true} which erase all comments, \n and \t. You will want to make sure that your js files fit this format.

Hope it helps !